# What is a nonstatic member function?

Tags: c++, methods, member, non-static

I am being told that I can't use the 'this' keyword in a class function. I'm coming from c# and i'm used to this working, but the compiler tells me that it can only be used within nonstatic member functions.

```
D3DXVECTOR3 position;

void Position(D3DXVECTOR3 position)
{
    this.position = position;
}
```

Comment: are you sure it worked in c#? in c#, a 'class function' is called a 'static method', and you cannot use 'this' in those either?

Comment: yeah I did it all the time to refer to a classes variable in the constructor, or is the constructor different?

Comment: Perhaps you should show the class this method belongs to - that might help clarify what you're doing

Answer (score 19, accepted):

this is a **pointer** containing the address of the object.

```
D3DXVECTOR3 position;

void YourClassNameHere::Position(D3DXVECTOR3 position)
{
    this->position = position;
}
```

Should work.

```
D3DXVECTOR3 position;

void YourClassNameHere::Position(D3DXVECTOR3 position)
{
    (*this).position = position;
}
```

Should also work.

Comment: @AndréCaron Heh, didn't notice. I edited to include MarkB's changes.

Comment: @AndréCaron Except that we don't know that, because he hasn't given us any context.

Answer (score 16):

In C++ you need to qualify your `Position` function with the class name:

`void YourClassNameHere::Position(D3DXVECTOR3 position)`

Also from @Pubby8's answer `this` is a pointer, not a reference so you need to use `this->position` instead (or consider using parameter names that don't shadow class members - I like using trailing `_` on my class members).

Also, C++ doesn't pass by reference by default so if `D3DXVECTOR3` is a complicated type you'll be copying a lot of data around. Consider passing it as `const D3DXVECTOR3& position` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Not only is `Position` a free function (not associated with a class) the way you wrote it, but `this` is also a pointer, not a reference.

```
D3DXVECTOR3 position;

void ClassName::Position(D3DXVECTOR3 position)
{
    this->position = position;
}
```

or, if that's supposed to be a constructor,

```
ClassName::ClassName(D3DXVECTOR3 p) : position(p)
{
}
```